# angularjs: issue while setting scope member when in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I face a very weird issue I cannot find my way out to fix it.

I've got $scope.categoryId used in a system menu to point to the current category.

In a ng-repeat thru categories, I have a ng-click that sets the current category, but doesn't work.
Even more weird, if I place a standalone tag, the thing works.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
<!-- click manages to inc -->
<p ng-click="categoryId = categoryId+1">++ : {{categoryId}}</p>

<!-- click doesn't manage to inc -->
<p 
    ng-repeat="c in categories"
    ng-click="categoryId = categoryId+1">
        {{$index}} : {{categoryId}}
</p>
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you post your controller? most probably is a problem due to the fact that ng-repeat creates a new scope.

Comment: Sorry but it works for me...I used a test array instead of categories http://plnkr.co/edit/JchT0GrkVjVUSzsLctxO?p=preview

Comment: @klode Sounds it is creating a new scope. I tried to mock up a fiddle, but alas, it works in my fiddle. My controller is large. One thing I see is the fact that the class="ng-scope" is present in the repeater, but not in the standalone p tag. What does it mean?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca it means a new child scope was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One thing I see is the fact that the class="ng-scope" is present in
>   the repeater, but not in the standalone p tag. What does it mean?

ng-repeat creates a new scope

categoryId should refer to the parent scope.

```
   <!-- click doesn't manage to inc -->
    <p 
        ng-repeat="c in [1,2,3]"
        ng-click="$parent.categoryId = $parent.categoryId+1">
            {{$index}} : {{$parent.categoryId}}
    </p>
```

Comment: You're right. That fixes the issue. The lesson: if I see a ng-scop class, this means a new scope has been create, right? One question though: why a new scope is created??

Comment: Yep,one tip to debug this kind of stuff is create a css class .ng-scope and add a red border.That way one can see all the scopes in the current page.

Answer (score 2):

ng-repeat will create a new scope. This might be the reason for your problem

A possible solution to this would be to create an object in the controller and then map this "categoryId" as a property of that object as follows:

`//In Controller
    var dummyObj = new Object();
    dummyObj.categoryId = //some value`

`//In View
    <p 
      ng-repeat="c in categories"
      ng-click="dummyObj.categoryId = dummyObj.categoryId+1">
        {{$index}} : {{dummyObj.categoryId}}
    </p>`

This should solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: Got it. But why in this case a new scope doesn't affect the dummyObj.categoryId? Sounds like there is one rule I'm missing regarding hg-repeat. In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/8UxY9/) I didn't manage to to create the same issue than in my project. Why?

Comment: Something to do with the way Angular handles it's scope variables and objects. When a new scope is created, it pushes the scope variables into a child scope. So you can find these variables in the $$childTail property of the current scope. However this behaviour doesn't exist for scope objects.

Comment: Just found an excellent answer on the same issue. See the following link for more details on why and how scoping works that way. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/802651